# gradlew build fails - Could not find classworlds.jar

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a project and running ./gradlew build fails for me and not my co worker. Gives me error 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':reference-verification:compileClasspath'.

  > Could not find classworlds.jar (classworlds:classworlds:1.1-alpha-2).

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is related to a library you are using. Maybe you lost authorization to the artifactory that you download classworlds jar or you might accidentaly made some errors in gradle files. I suggest you to check your permission if not works, try to delete and pull the code again. If it works in your co-workers computer it has to be related to something not so obvious.